# spree_chimpy:merge_vars:sync rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, spree, mailchimp

I am installing the gem `spree_chimpy` from `https://github.com/watg/spree_chimpy` in my Ruby on Rails application with *spree*. After doing mailchimp setup I am notifying mailchimp about `merge_vars` which seem to cause the error. When I run the command

```
rake spree_chimpy:merge_vars:sync --trace
```

I get the error `"tag" must be 10 bytes and may only contain "A-Z 0-9 _`. I don't understand the error, I have nowhere added any `tag` variable in the configuration. For reference, my `config/initializers/spree_chimpy.rb` is pasted here:

```
    Spree::Chimpy.config do |config|
  # your API key as provided by MailChimp
  config.key = '<#my-api-hash-key>'

  # extra api options for the Mailchimp gem
  # config.api_options = { throws_exceptions: false, timeout: 3600 }

  # name of your list, defaults to "Members"
  config.list_name = 'test'

  # Allow users to be subscribed by default. Defaults to false
  # If you enable this option, it's strongly advised that your enable
  # double_opt_in as well. Abusing this may cause Mailchimp to suspend your account.
  # config.subscribed_by_default = false

  # When double-opt is enabled, the user will receive an email
  # asking to confirm their subscription. Defaults to false
  config.double_opt_in = false

  # id of your store. max 10 letters. defaults to "spree"
  # config.store_id = 'acme'

  # define a list of merge vars:
  # - key: a unique name that mail chimp uses. 10 letters max
  # - value: the name of any method on the user class.
  # default is {'EMAIL' => :email}
  config.merge_vars = {
    'EMAIL'       => :email,
    'FNAME'       => :fname,
    'LNAME'       => :lname,
    'ORDERNUMBER' => :onumber
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is being thrown is from somewhere around here:

https://github.com/watg/spree_chimpy/blob/7ba5d855112050e1b61c2d0a3369bc08f254842d/lib/spree_chimpy.rb#L59-L62

The actual error is within the mailchimp API client.  You're getting the error because ORDERNUMBER has 11 characters in it.  If you trim it down to 10 characters, you should be okay.